# Apollo client cache redirects with cacheRedirects on nested objects without args

Tags: frontend, apollo-client

I have a question about the cacheRedirects.

I have one component that queries the user login information:

```
query LoggedIn {
    loggedIn {
      user {
        ...CurrentUser
      }
      accessToken:
      newLogin: Boolean
   }
}
```

I then have another self-contained component that renders an individual result and some info about its user. I'm using the following query, which will be fully cached already by the previous one, so we shouldn't need a network hit:

```
query CurrentUser {
  currentUser {
    ...CurrentUser
  }
}
```

However I'm not sure how to set up cacheRedirects so that I can avoid the unnecessary network query?
I saw the samples on Internet and find the query in them are all has "args", but my query doesn't have it since I put it into http header, which means the args in currentUser: (_, args, { getCacheKey }) is null.

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
    dataIdFromObject: (object: any) => {
      switch (object.__typename) {
          return object.username;
        default:
          return defaultDataIdFromObject(object);
      }
    },
    cacheRedirects: {
      Query: {
        currentUser: (_, args, { getCacheKey }) => {
          getCacheKey({ __typename: 'CurrentUser' });
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

The above does not work. Thanks!